# Create a new dataset based given operation column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am using spark-sql-2.3.1v and have the below scenario:

Given a dataset:

```
val ds = Seq(
  (1, "x1", "y1", "0.1992019"),
  (2, null, "y2", "2.2500000"),
  (3, "x3", null, "15.34567"),
  (4, null, "y4", null),
  (5, "x4", "y4", "0")
   ).toDF("id","col_x", "col_y","value")
```

**i.e.**

```
+---+-----+-----+---------+
| id|col_x|col_y|    value|
+---+-----+-----+---------+
|  1|   x1|   y1|0.1992019|
|  2| null|   y2|2.2500000|
|  3|   x3| null| 15.34567|
|  4| null|   y4|     null|
|  5|   x4|   y4|        0|
+---+-----+-----+---------+
```

**Requirement:**

I get operational column (i.e., `operationCol`) on which I need to perform some calculation from outside.

When performing some operations on column "col_x", I need to create a new dataset by filtering out all records which have "col_x" null values and return that new dataset.

Likewise when performing some operations on column "col_y", I need to create a new dataset by filter out all records which have "col_y" null values and return that new dataset.

**Example:**

```
val operationCol ="col_x";

if(operationCol === "col_x"){
  //filter out all rows which has "col_x" null and return that new dataset.
}

if(operationCol === "col_y"){
  //filter out all rows which has "col_y" null and return that new dataset.
}
```

**When operationCol === "col_x" expected output:**

```
+---+-----+-----+---------+
| id|col_x|col_y|    value|
+---+-----+-----+---------+
|  1|   x1|   y1|0.1992019|
|  3|   x3| null| 15.34567|
|  5|   x4|   y4|        0|
+---+-----+-----+---------+
```

**When operationCol === "col_y" expected output:**

```
+---+-----+-----+---------+
| id|col_x|col_y|    value|
+---+-----+-----+---------+
|  1|   x1|   y1|0.1992019|
|  2| null|   y2|2.2500000|
|  4| null|   y4|     null|
|  5|   x4|   y4|        0|
+---+-----+-----+---------+
```

How to achieve this expected output? 
In other words, how can the branching of dataframe be done? How to create a new dataframe/dataset in the middle of the flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`df.na.drop()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameNaFunctions.html#drop-java.lang.String:A-) to drop rows that contains nulls. The drop function can take a list of the columns you want to consider as input, so in this case, you can write it as follows:

```
val newDf = df.na.drop(Seq(operationCol))
```

This will create a new dataframe `newDf` with where all rows in `operationCol` have been removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `filter` to filter out null values.

```
scala> val operationCol = "col_x" // for one column
operationCol: String = col_x

scala> ds.filter(col(operationCol).isNotNull).show(false)
+---+-----+-----+---------+
|id |col_x|col_y|value    |
+---+-----+-----+---------+
|1  |x1   |y1   |0.1992019|
|3  |x3   |null |15.34567 |
|5  |x4   |y4   |0        |
+---+-----+-----+---------+


scala> val operationCol = Seq("col_x","col_y") // For multiple Columns
operationCol: Seq[String] = List(col_x, col_y)

scala> ds.filter(operationCol.map(col(_).isNotNull).reduce(_ && _)).show
+---+-----+-----+---------+
| id|col_x|col_y|    value|
+---+-----+-----+---------+
|  1|   x1|   y1|0.1992019|
|  5|   x4|   y4|        0|
+---+-----+-----+---------+
```